# Django Class Based Views TemplateView perform redirect if user is logged in

Tags: django

I'm rewriting my function views to class based views, the previous login page below

```
def login(request, template_name="login.html"):
    context = {}

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

would check to see if your already logged in, if yes would redirect you to the homepage

how can i do the same with a templateview below?

```
class LoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "login.html"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the **`get(...)`** method

```
class LoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "login.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```